# jQuery extract words from string

Tags: jquery, string

I have a simple question. Using jQuery I want to extract words in a string to an arrary. How do I do this? Any examples?

e.g. If I have a string as shown below: I want to get only the words with the '@' prefix

```
var accts = "@userA @userB @userC   @userD invalidUserE @userF ";
```

Thanks,
K.R.

Comment: are you trying to do this for twitter usernames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery, you can do this quite simply with basic JavaScript:

```
var accts = "@userA @userB @userC   @userD invalidUserE @userF ";
var split = accts.split(" ");
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if(split[i].charAt(0) == "@") {
      //Got one
    } 
}
```

You can do whatever you want to do with the strings as you find each one. You should also be able to use a regular expression.

Comment: Using `split[i].charAt(0) == "@"` would be O(1) per iteration instead of O(n) searching through every string for any occurrence of `@`.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill - Thanks, that's a good point. I've updated the example. So the above comment still makes sense, I originally used `if(split[i].indexOf("@") == 0)` instead of the `charAt` method.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for jquery

```
var result = $.grep(accts.split(" "), function(a){ return /^@/.test(a) } )
```

Gives you:

```
["@userA", "@userB", "@userC", "@userD", "@userF"]
```

Answer (score 2):

matches = accts.match(/(@\S+)/g)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Javascript [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function. For example:

```
var a = accts.split(" ");
```

Once you have the space-separated words in an array, iterate through the array to select the ones starting with `@` as you require.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use jQuery, it won't help in this instance.  The best way to do this is to use a regular expression to identify a valid user, in this case a string beginning with the `@` character.  This code extract all strings starting with an @ symbol from your string:

Unlike the previous examples using split on the `@` symbol it will ignore anything not starting with an `@` and only return what's valid without the need for extra tests.

```
var accts = "@userA @userB @userC   @userD invalidUserE @userF ";
var user = null;
var patt = /@\w+/g;
while(user=patt.exec(accts))
{
    alert(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I have the same need for #tags also, I use above answers but i think they are not giving me the correct results when i Have strings like this

```
var accts = "a@userA @userB @userC   @userD invalidUserE @userF@userG ";
```

I have updated the above code hope it will help peoples

Demo on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abdulrauf6182012/3LBsC/

code :

**Html**

```
<div class="output"></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


function getHasTagAry( msgTxt, finder ) {     
     var msgTxtAry = msgTxt.split(' ');
     var hash = []
     for(var i = 0; i < msgTxtAry.length; i++) {
         if( msgTxtAry[i].indexOf(finder) > -1 )
         hash.push( msgTxtAry[i].trim() )
     }
    msgTxtAry = hash.join('').split(finder).join('-tp-'+finder).split('-tp-');
    hash = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < msgTxtAry.length; i++) {
        if( msgTxtAry[i].trim() != '' ){
         hash.push( msgTxtAry[i].trim() )         
        }

     }
    return hash;
}    

     var msgTxt = 'hellow #ABDULRAUF #RUFI #HASHTAG #HASHTAGFINDER abc #GAME';
     var hash2 = getHasTagAry( msgTxt,'#' );     

     $('.output').append( 'hash tags in string='+hash2.length+'<br/>' );
     $('.output').append( hash2.join('<br/>') );

   $('.output').append( '<br/><br/><br/>');


     var msgTxt = 'Hi @ABDULRAUF @RUFI  @username abc @AA';
     var userNames = getHasTagAry( msgTxt ,'@');     
 $('.output').append( userNames.length+'user names in str('+msgTxt+')<br/><br/>' );
 $('.output').append( userNames.join('<br/>') );



});
```

If any one can optimize the code it would be great :) , I have very short time for it